# Eclipse indentation on Emacs

Tags: java, eclipse, emacs

I'm an emacs user who just started working for a new company where eclipse is the standard.  I've tried eclipse, but I want to also experiment with JDEE (I'm coming back to Java after a long hiatus).  The major stumbling block so far is getting the indentation to match.  Is there an easy way to do this, or am I going to need to dig deeply into the nuts and bolts of emacs indentation?

EDIT: sorry for the confusion in this question: I do not want to get Eclipse to mimic emacs, I want emacs to mimic Eclipse.  I want to be able to use emacs to modify code without screwing up the indentation that the Eclipse users expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to customize the indentation in java mode. Take a look [here](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Indentation-Engine-Basics.html#Indentation-Engine-Basics), [here](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Customizing-Indentation.html#Customizing-Indentation) and [here](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Adding-Styles.html#Adding-Styles).

Comment: Yeah, this is the sort of nuts and bolts I was trying to avoid because of some of the peculiarities of Eclipse indentation (or at least the style of it that they are using).  I was hoping that somebody had already programmed an Eclipse-style that I could just drop in.  Thanks for the refs tho.

Comment: Well, if you ever get it done - could you publish the alist? May be even here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556558/getting-consistent-indentation-in-eclipse-and-emacs for a good, simple start. As Arkadiy said, if anybody nails this, please post!

Answer (score 9):

The main difference I found between Eclipse (and IntelliJ) and Emacs default java formatting is that Emacs lines up function arguments continued onto a new line with the previous arguments e.g. emacs does:

```
BigLongJavaStuff.doFoobarToQuux("argument 1",
                                "argument 2");
```

and Eclipse does:

```
BigLongJavaStuff.doFoobarToQuux("argument 1",
        "argument 2");
```

The following added to you ~/.emacs file will make Emacs java-mode do the same:

```
;; eclipse-java-style is the same as the "java" style (copied from
;; cc-styles.el) with the addition of (arglist-cont-nonempty . ++) to
;; c-offsets-alist to make it more like default Eclipse formatting -- function
;; arguments starting on a new line are indented by 8 characters
;; (++ = 2 x normal offset) rather than lined up with the arguments on the
;; previous line
(defconst eclipse-java-style
  '((c-basic-offset . 4)
    (c-comment-only-line-offset . (0 . 0))
    ;; the following preserves Javadoc starter lines
    (c-offsets-alist . ((inline-open . 0)
                        (topmost-intro-cont    . +)
                        (statement-block-intro . +)
                        (knr-argdecl-intro     . 5)
                        (substatement-open     . +)
                        (substatement-label    . +)
                        (label                 . +)
                        (statement-case-open   . +)
                        (statement-cont        . +)
                        (arglist-intro  . c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren)
                        (arglist-close  . c-lineup-arglist)
                        (access-label   . 0)
                        (inher-cont     . c-lineup-java-inher)
                        (func-decl-cont . c-lineup-java-throws)
                        (arglist-cont-nonempty . ++)
                        )))
  "Eclipse Java Programming Style")
(c-add-style "ECLIPSE" eclipse-java-style)
(customize-set-variable 'c-default-style (quote ((java-mode . "eclipse") (awk-mode . "awk") (other . "gnu"))))
```

Comment: The related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556558/getting-consistent-indentation-in-eclipse-and-emacs relates to the very basic issue of tabs and spaces which solves the first 90%. Answer posted above tries to address a piece of the remaninig 10%, from what I can tell.

Comment: I found this very helpful!  I had to change it a bit to get the behavior I wanted -- I wanted to be able to start the argument list on the line after the method invocation itself.   Add (arglist-intro . +) (arglist-cont . +) after (arglist-cont-nonempty . +).  (I also changed ++ to +)

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by making Eclipse's indentation match Emacs.  But you can modify indentation here:
`Windows->Preferences-General->Editors`

Click on the 'Text Editors' option, and you'll see the tab width properties.

One more little note, Eclipse has Emacs-style key bindings built into it:
`Windows->Preferences->General->Keys`

Under 'Scheme', there's an option for Emacs.

Note: you can also modify the format of your Java code here:
`Windows->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter`