# Getting consistent indentation in Eclipse and Emacs

Tags: eclipse, emacs, indentation

I am looking to start using emacs for php development. So far I have been using eclipse.

I installed the Nxhtml mode in emacs (GNU Emacs23) for this. But I observe that when a file edited in emacs is opened in eclipse the indentation breaks. In eclipse I have the following settings,

> tab policy = spaces, indentation = 4

In emacs, I have this line in my .emacs file

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
```

Now lets say I create a file using emacs with the following contents

```
<?php 

class HelloWorld {

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }

}
```

If its opened in eclipse now, it shows

```
<?php 

class HelloWorld {

    public function __construct() {
    echo 'Hello World';
    }

}
```

If its indented in eclipse now by pressing tab, then emacs shows too much indentation.

NOTE: in eclipse when ENTER is pressed to go to the new line, the code gets automatically indented just the way it happens in emacs using `C-j`

I am unable to figure out whether it is emacs or eclipse that causing this and what needs to be configured to solve this issue.

I work with people who mainly use eclipse. The indentation problem is the only thing thats stopping me from switching over to emacs.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: in eclipse turn on "show whitespace" and you will see the cause.  In rad (a variation of eclipse) this is on the general ! editors ! text editors preference page.  It may be the same in non-rad eclipse.  Just type white in the filter bos on the preferences page and you will see it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It seems emacs is not configured to add spaces in place of a tab. I was under the impression that thats the default setting in emacs. How do I configure this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not used emacs in this century, so I'm no help wit it.

Comment: no problem. i found out through google search and it works fine now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this in future, the variable controlling tab indentation is `indent-tabs-mode`

Also, if you're trying to work out what's going on with the whitespace, you might try the `whitespace-mode` command (use `M-x whitespace mode`): it shows tabs and spaces etc. much more clearly. The command toggles if you want to turn it off again.